# Displaying all of apiList data to console flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development

I'm trying to get api data from pixabay which returns a list of hits and the hits contain a list of the imgurls like so
[image]

and the hits contain the imageurls like so
[image]

I have tried to parse the following with the following code

```
    class Hit {
  final int hit;
  final int totalhit;
  final List <HitData> hitsdata;

  Hit({
    this.hit,
    this.totalhit,
    this.hitsdata,


});


  factory Hit.fromJson (Map<String, dynamic> jsondata){
    var list = jsondata['hits'] as List;
    List <HitData> imageDetails = list.map((e) => HitData.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return Hit(
      hit: jsondata['total'],
      totalhit: jsondata['totalHits'],
      hitsdata: imageDetails,
    );
  }
}

class HitData {
  final int downloads;
  final String imgUrl;
  final String midImgUrl;
  final int likes;
  final int comments;

  HitData({
    this.downloads,
    this.comments,
    this.imgUrl,
    this.likes,
    this.midImgUrl,
  });

  factory HitData.fromJson (Map<String, dynamic> parsedjson) {
    return HitData(
      downloads: parsedjson['downloads'],
      comments: parsedjson['comments'],
      imgUrl: parsedjson['largeImageURL'],
      midImgUrl: parsedjson['webformatURL'],
      likes: parsedjson['likes'],
    );
  }

}
```

and i try to print the value of image urls to consoles with this

```
Future getData () async{
    try {
      http.Response dataresponse = await http.get(kUrl);
      if (dataresponse.statusCode == 200)
       {
         var bodyData = jsonDecode(dataresponse.body);
         Hit hit =  Hit.fromJson(bodyData);
         print(hit.);
       }
      else {
        print('lil error');
        }
    }catch (e){
      print("Unable to get object");
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

but the console returns a list that is filled with instance of Hitdata instead of any actual data .
please what have i done wrong here

Comment: No screenshots of text please.  Paste the text enclosed with ``` on a line by itself both before and after the text.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom `toString()` method in the `HitData` class to print the properties as we desire:

```
@override
String toString() {
 return """HitData {
            downloads: ${this.downloads},
            imgUrl: ${this.imgUrl},
            midImgUrl: ${this.midImgUrl},
            likes: ${this.likes},
            comments: ${this.comments},
          }
          """;
}
```

So the whole `Class` could be:

```
class HitData {
  final int downloads;
  final String imgUrl;
  final String midImgUrl;
  final int likes;
  final int comments;

  HitData({
    this.downloads,
    this.comments,
    this.imgUrl,
    this.likes,
    this.midImgUrl,
  });

  factory HitData.fromJson (Map<String, dynamic> parsedjson) {
    return HitData(
      downloads: parsedjson['downloads'],
      comments: parsedjson['comments'],
      imgUrl: parsedjson['largeImageURL'],
      midImgUrl: parsedjson['webformatURL'],
      likes: parsedjson['likes'],
    );
  }
  @override
  String toString() {
    return """HitData {
               downloads: ${this.downloads},
               imgUrl: ${this.imgUrl},
               midImgUrl: ${this.midImgUrl},
               likes: ${this.likes},
               comments: ${this.comments},
             }
             """;
  }
}
```

Therefore, when calling the `print(hitdata)` function, the console will display the data as we expect.

Comment: does this still display them in a list